# Is this the expected/wanted outcomes using html snapshots and google fetch? SEO/SPA

Tags: seo, fetch-as-google

Just got html snapshots working with the help of html-snapshot node module & following htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]
```

It is an angular application, but the question is universal to javascript spas/seo. Looked around the web found a good amount of articles but nothing complete which is surprising since seo is pretty important. In any case 3 questions

**Using google fetch to confirm the proper outcome**

1. **The rendering of the snapshot pages:** Is the intention not to worry about the css or images or possible layout issues. For example, here is an example of a [page of mine](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1UtLF9ZEXTidXlMZWQwQUtwQ0U). The links and the main content are overlapping each other. Is that something we should be concerned about?
2. **Orange warming redirected label:** This message is only warning us of the expected redirect, not that there is an issue that need to fix?
   [See image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UtLF9ZEXTiMC1qZFBoQTMzNHc/view?usp=sharing)
3. **Submit to index:** Should we? My first assumption was not to and just make sure site and that is submitted.

Comment: The use of `_escaped_fragment_ ` is not recommended any more: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Comment: @Quentin thanks. But just to reinforce my reading of that we should maintain ` <meta name="fragment" content="!">`for javascript framework sites(spas), but get away from any pre-rendering/snapshots/use of escape fragment convention

Comment: No. Don't use `_escaped_fragment_`. Don't use `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`. Do use [the History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). When the browser directly requests `/foo/example` (e.g. from a link from an external site, or a bookmark, or the user typing the URL) then **do generate the HTML for entire page on the server**. When a user follows a link on your site to `/foo/example` then use JS to transform the DOM to match what the server would render and use `pushState` to set the URL to `/foo/example` so that you don't have to load the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the help of @Quentin & this [link](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) that was provided, I got enough to answer to my question.

1. It's recommended not to use the escaped fragment convention
2. And if you are looking to use it with the intention to degrade gracefully, suit other search engines the bottom line is to not use snapshots or at least in this convention. According to google

> In general, websites shouldn't pre-render pages only for Google -- we expect that you might pre-render pages for performance benefits for users and that you would follow progressive enhancement guidelines. **If you pre-render pages, make sure that the content served to Googlebot matches the user's experience, both how it looks and how it interacts**. Serving Googlebot different content than a normal user would see is considered cloaking, and would be against our Webmaster Guidelines.